# Angularjs placement for event which will be used sitewide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events, angular-ui

I have this event:

```
  $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
            //do something
        });
```

Instead of putting this event on each controller, I want to know if its possible to put this event on one place and then use it site wide in Angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could put it in your module's `.run()`.

```
angular.module('yourModule')
    .run(function() {
        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
            //do something
        });
    });
```

According to the AngularJS module [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the services have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.